# Using angular2-busy with ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm using the `angular2-busy` module which is referenced by a subscription of an `Observable`.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-busy

I have variable `busy` of type `Subscription`.

```
this.busy = this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => 
this.httpService.getSiteData(+params.get('')))
.subscribe()
```

With the current code, the loading screen hangs even after the data has loaded. I know this is an issue with using the `route` of type `ActivatedRoute` becuase on my other calls where it is simply attached to the `Observable` subscription, it works. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by breaking my code into two parts:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {this.site_no_temp = 
+params['']});
```

And then using that `site_no_temp` variable in the actual http service which I was able to assign to `busy`.

```
this.busy = this.httpService.getSiteData(this.site_no_temp)
.subscribe()
```